# Lining controls up very precisely

Tags: formatting, microsoft-access

i have about 50 labels that are each just barely big enough to fit the letter `x` in them. the labels are on a report. i need to align all the labels very precisely.

is there an easier way to do this than trusting my eyes?

Comment: doubleudoubleudoubleu.superuser.com

Comment: You keep asking variations on the same question over and over again, and not a single one of them is a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**

Go into design mode.
Right click on one of the labels that is where you want it, and choose properties.
Note the value of the **Top** parameter (if you're lining them up horizontally).
Now select them all at once.
When they are all selected put the original parameter value in the now blank **Top** field, and hit Enter.

Note that there is also a Left field for horizontal placement.

Answer (score 3):

In design view, you can bump the controls that have the focus by one pixel by holding down the Ctrl key and using the arrows keys to move them in the desired direction.  Each arrow keypress moves the selected controls by one pixel in the direction of the arrow.

Then, you can check their alignment by clicking and dragging over your design surface to create a rectangle. Use the line of the leading edge of the selection rectangle as a straightedge, and position it over the edge of the controls you are checking for alignment.

You can also use Align Top, Align Left, and so forth to align all of the selected controls along the top or left edge, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Place the top control in the right location.

Select it and all the others.

A2003 and before:

From the format menu, choose ALIGN then LEFT.

A2007/A2010:

From the ribbon, choose ARRANGE then LEFT (under Control Alignment).